# Pattern matching on elements of a list

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a list with elements of a type that has multiple constructors (e.g. something like [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hsemail/1.7.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Rfc2822.html#g:12)). How can I extract element(s) of the list that match a particular constructor?

One way I could figure out was using list comprehension. E.g. given a list `fields` with elements of type `Field` from above example, I could extract the first `From` field:

```
from = head [head f | From f <- fields]
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: I don't see, why can't you just match the (From f :: _) ?  Or use a let f = match ..

Answer (score 1):

To filter the list that match the `From` constructor, you can use the `filter` function:

```
filter (\x -> case x of From {} -> True; _ -> False) fields
```

and then take the `head` to take the first element.

```
head . filter (\x -> case x of From {} -> True; _ -> False) $ fields
```